# is it possible to using std::pair as key of std::set without any duplicates each element?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm trying to store struct in `std::set` using two integers in struct as key.
I know that is possible to using `std::pair` as key of `std::set`.

```
struct TYPE{
  pair<int, int> nums;
  ... // some other things

  TYPE(){}
  TYPE(int first, int second) { nums = make_pair(first, second); }
  bool operator<(const TYPE &rhs) const{
    return nums < rhs.nums;
  }
};
set<TYPE> nums_set;
nums_set.insert(TYPE(1, 2));
nums_set.insert(TYPE(1, 4));
nums_set.insert(TYPE(5, 2));
// size of set : 3, (1,2)(1,4)(5,2)
auto it = nums_set.find(TYPE(1, 2)); // find return (1,2)
```

However, I want searchable and no duplicates `std::set`, regardless of the order of the elements in `std::pair`.
like this :

```
nums_set.insert(TYPE(1, 2));
nums_set.insert(TYPE(1, 4)); // failed. duplicate 1
nums_set.insert(TYPE(4, 2)); // failed. duplicate 2
nums_set.insert(TYPE(4, 1)); // failed. duplicate 1
nums_set.insert(TYPE(3, 4));
// size of set : 2, (1,2)(3,4)
auto it = nums_set.find(TYPE(2, 7));  // find return (1,2).
```

easiest solution so far is use `std::vector` instead and do duplicate check before inserting into the vector like this:

```cpp
auto fn = [](const TYPE& e, const TYPE&& t){
    return e.nums.first == t.nums.first ||
            e.nums.first == t.nums.second ||
            e.nums.second == t.nums.first ||
            e.nums.second == t.nums.second;
};
vector<TYPE> nums_vec;
nums_vec.push_back(TYPE(1, 2));
if(nums_vec.end() == find_if(nums_vec.begin(), nums_vec.end(), 
  bind(fn, placeholders::_1, TYPE(1,4))))
{  nums_vec.push_back(TYPE(1,4)); }
```

However, I feel it's not a good idea to do this for every insert to avoid duplication.
So, my question is, is it possible to implement these features with `std::set` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison used for a set must satisfy the [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) named requirement. Among these requirements is transitivity of the induced equivalence relation:

> If `equivalent(a,b)` and `equivalent(b,c)` then `equivalent(a,c)`.

A concrete case:

- Let `a` be `{1,2}`, `b` be `{1,4}`, and `c` be `{3,4}`.
- **Transitivity:** if `{1,2}` is equivalent to `{1,4}` and `{1,4}` is equivalent to `{3,4}` then `{1,2}` is equivalent to `{3,4}`.

Another way to express that `X` is equivalent to `Y` is that the presence of `X` in your set prevents `Y` from being added. You want `{1,2}` to prevent `{1,4}` from being added to the set. You want `{1,4}` to prevent `{3,4}` from being added to the set. To have the required transitivity, it is **required** that `{1,2}` prevent `{3,4}` from being added to the set, which is something you do **not** want.

No, your goal cannot be achieved solely by the ordering used by the set.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought it would be possible somehow, so I thought about it for few hours, but after reading your answers, everything became clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict weak ordering that you can use, so you cannot use `std::set`.

However, you can use `std::unordered_set` which only requires to provide equality.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check unordered_set.